# Ошибка "Access denied for user"

Tags: xampp, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, с нижеследующей проблемой.

> `Добро пожаловать в phpMyAdmin.
> Ошибка
> Ответ MySQL:
>     #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> Не удалось установить подключение для пользователя указанного в директиве controluser, с помощью параметров определенных в конфигурационном файле config.inc.php.
> phpMyAdmin не смог установить соединение с сервером MySQL. Проверьте хост, имя пользователя и пароль установленные в конфигурационном файле config.inc.php и удостоверьтесь, что они соответствуют данным полученным от администратора сервера MySQL.`

Answer (score 1):

это вы так запускаете сайт локалхосте если да то вам нужно правильно установить соединение с базой данных указать пароль имя(которое вы назначили в phpmyadmin)саму базу.

Comment: а где это менять не подскажите по подробнее? спасибо

Comment: ну это вы должны указывать при поключении к базе обычно подключение пишется так когда делают запросы к базе 
<?
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","здесь имя","здесь пароль");
mysql_select_db("имя базы",$db);
?>

Comment: вы примерно скажите что делали тогда будет понятна проблема

Comment: спасибо я уже решил данную поблему!